Tabulator accessibility and WCAG 1.3.1 question and rowheader
In the numerous examples of Tabulator the column headers are accurately described in the DOM as role="columnheader". However, even with frozen rows or row heading options, the row headers are marked as role="gridcell", and not role="rowheader".
This feels like an issue to me, but maybe I've missed a configuration option?
At the moment a screen reader will only tell me verbosely the column title, but concisely the row number (not row heading name) i'm on when navigating around the table in table mode (NVDA: T, ctrl+alt+arrow).
Also doesn't change visible focus rect when navigating - unsure if that's also a fail or just a quirk of screen reading, but i can activate the sort icons and not have a visible focus rect, which is odd.
Should I log a bug for these issues?
I think in the spirit of WCAG 1.3.1 this failure to read out the row headings is a fail, but ultimately reading the row number is probably a weak 'pass'.

Hi Giles. Could you please try to focus the question? You state that the examples work correctly. But then you mention that they don’t without explaining the context. Am I assuming correctly that in your code it doesn’t work? If so, you will need to share you code so that people can help you.

Navigation through tab stops with the tab key, and reading navigation with arrow keys in a table are very different things. It’s normal that the reading position in the table is not indicated visually. It might be an option you can switch on in NVDA, not sure.

@Andy Let's focus on the primary issue - role="rowheaders". Tabulator in its own examples, and configurations that i've tried, never provides the correct role for rowheaders, it is using gridcell regardless of if you use frozen row headings and this is inconsistent with its behaviour when dealing with column headers, which it gets right. Hope that helps.

For your main issue with the row headers you should file a bug. Good catch!
I saw that there is a rowHeader option in Tabulator, but that example doesn’t use the right role either.
This is a pretty clear Failure of Success Criterion 1.3.1 for not correctly marking up table headers (F91):

This failure occurs when data tables do not use […] the ARIA columnheader and rowheader) roles […]

